# How to update or refresh DataGridView after inserting a row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to update a datagridview in window form application.
Here is my code.

```
    string[] row = new string[] { Word, txturl.Text, Url, NumOfMatch.ToString() };
    gridview1.Rows.Add(row);
    gridview1.Refresh();
    gridview1.Update();
```

However when I click on the datagridview the values appear. Why is that?

Comment: please see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560559/c-sharp-how-do-i-refresh-datagridview-after-removing-rows>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

> ```
> string[] row = new string[] { Word, txturl.Text, Url, NumOfMatch.ToString() };
> gridview1.Rows.Add(row);
> gridview1.Refresh();
> gridview1.Update();
> ```

Try using

```
            string[] row = new string[] { Word, txturl.Text, Url, NumOfMatch.ToString() };
        gridview1.Rows.Add(row);
        gridview1.Focus();
```

Comment: actualy I had to invoke a deligate in order to work because the process is multithread. So your code worked now fine. Ty